# PHP connected to db can't use insert function

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been sitting on the same small problem now for over 10 hours, so it's time to ask stackoverflow! I'm connected to the database but when calling mysqli_stmt_bind_param I get "invalid object or resource".

I've tried the insert statement in the console and it works fine..

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "myUsername", "password");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "webshop");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query= mysqli_stmt_init($con);

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($query, "INSERT INTO user (name, email, hash, address, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ssssi", $name, $email, $hash, $address, $tel);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($query))
    {
        mysqli_close($con);
    }

?>
```

Thankful for any help at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_init` is needed as you are accessing mysqli using the procedural style.

This returns an object of type `mysqli_stmt`, which then acts as a container for the query you are building. As such, you should pass this as the first parameter to `mysqli_stmt_prepare`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` and `mysqli_stmt_execute`.

So your code would look like:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "myUsername", "password");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "webshop");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $query =  "INSERT INTO user (name, email, hash, address, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $name, $email, $hash, $address, $tel);
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
    {
        mysqli_close($stmt);
    }

?>
```

One, unrelated point - you appear to be requiring that your `tel` field (which I presume to be a telephone number) is an integer. This might be a bad idea if you have to handle telephone numbers starting with 0 (common in the UK for example) at any point.

Comment: Yes this is the way to use mysqli correctly. It's kinda the same as my originally solution. The problem I had was not this code, but that my user I used wasn't privileged to access insert. Which was very hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the statement object returned by `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, email, hash, address, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $name, $email, $hash, $address, $tel);
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
```

Also, the `mysqli_stmt_init($con)` call is not needed (I think).

Comment: If I erase the init function then prepare gets an error "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given". Is this telling me something is wrong with the connection?

anyway, if I keep init and uses the new $stmt in param I get "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given". So I guess $stmt is returning false, but why.